# What is the proper way to translate a complicated SQL query with custom columns and rdbms-specific functions to Doctrine

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, orm, propel

I have been a Propel user for years and only recently started switching to Doctrine. It's still quite new to me and sometimes Propel habits kick in and make it hard form me to "think in Doctrine". Below is a specific case. **You don't have to know Propel to answer my question - I also present my case in raw SQL.**

Simplified structure of the tables that my query refers is like this:

- Application table has FK to Admin which has FK to User (fos_user in the DB)
- ApplicationUser table has FK to Application

My query gets all Application records with custom columns containing additional info retrieved from related User records (through Admin) and some COUNTs of related ApplicationUser objects, one of which is additionally filtered (`adminname`, `usercount`, `usercountperiod` columns added to the query).

I have a Propel query like this:

```
ApplicationQuery::create()
->leftJoinApplicationUser()
->useAdminQuery()
    ->leftJoinUser()
->endUse()
->withColumn('fos_user.username', 'adminname')
->withColumn('COUNT(application_user.id)', 'usercount')
->withColumn('COUNT(application_user.id) FILTER '
    . '(WHERE score > 0 AND '
    . ' application_user.created_at >= to_timestamp('.strtotime($users_scored['begin']).') and '
    . ' application_user.created_at < to_timestamp('.strtotime($users_scored['end']).') )', 'usercountperiod')
->groupById()
->groupBy('User.Id')
->orderById('DESC') 
->paginate( ....
```

This is how it translates to SQL (PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT application.id, application.name, ..., 
    fos_user.username AS "adminname",
    COUNT(socialscore_application_user.id) AS "usercount", 
    COUNT(application_user.id) FILTER (
        WHERE score > 0 AND 
            application_user.created_at >= to_timestamp(1491004800) and 
            application_user.created_at < to_timestamp(1498780800) ) AS "usercountperiod" 
FROM application 
    LEFT JOIN application_user ON (application.id=application_user.application_id) 
    LEFT JOIN admin ON (application.admin_id=admin.id) 
    LEFT JOIN fos_user ON (admin.id=fos_user.id) 
    GROUP BY application.id,fos_user.id 
    ORDER BY application.id DESC
    LIMIT 15
```

As you can see it's quite complex (in terms of translating it to Doctrine ORM, when you're a Doctrine newbie like me :) ). It uses specific features of PostgreSQL:

- being able to include only Primary Key in GROUP BY statement, while other columns from the same table can be used in SELECT without aggregating function or inclusion in GROUP BY (because they are "dependent" on the PK);
- FILTER which allows you to further filter records that are fed into aggregate functions

It also uses some joins and adds custom columns (`adminname`, `usercount`, `usercountperiod`) which I can access in my resulting Propel Model objects (with functions like `$result->getAdminname()`.

**My question is: what is the "Doctrine way" to achieve as similar thing as possible as simply as possible** (use some PostgreSQL-specific or any RDBMS-specific features, add some custom columns which will be accessible through ORM objects and so on)?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I fail to see how this could be answered without knowing that Doctrine thing (and besides: that query is far from being "quite complex" - it's a pretty straightforward way of doing things. And except for the `limit` clause (and the useless `to_timestamp()`) it is actually standard SQL. Regarding the "abbreviated"  `group by` I would assume that can be solved in your obfuscation layer by adding all columns to the `groupBy('User.Id')` call

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - you misread the description - I wrote that you don't have to know Propel to help me. Doctrine knowledge is obviously needed :-) And by "complex" I meant "complex regarding my limited knowledge of Doctrine ORM", not "complex SQL-wise". This PostgreSQL GROUP BY feature of using only PK isn't a crucial thing for me. The most important thing is how to do any RDBMS-specific things like those in Doctrine in a concise manner.

Comment: Why don't you create a `View` from this query and then define a matching `Model`?